# Java equals transitive relationship

Tags: java, equals

I'm trying to implement an object equality based on the following requirements:

```
class MyObject {
  String x;
  String y;
}
```

1) if both properties on the 2 objects being compared are non-null then they are equal if   x.equals(x) && y.equals(y)

2) if at least one x is null on any of the objects being compared then they are equal if y.equals(y) (assuming both y are non-null)

3) if at least one y is null on any of the objects being compared then they are equal if x.equals(x) (assuming both x are non-null)

After a few attempts I'm starting to think that is not possible to achieve the transitive relationship of the equals method based on these requirements. Comments are welcome! Thks.

Comment: Please indicate if this is homework.

Comment: show your broken code for equals() method implemented.

Comment: You haven't explained whether ("x", null) is equal to (null, "y")

Comment: Your numbered list is basically psuedocode, so just convert that into actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from those three requirements, you're right; you don't get transitivity.

Take these examples:

```
x = "hello", y = "mom"
x = "hello", y = null
x = "hello", y = "world"
```

By what you say, the first and second are equal, the second and third are equal, but the first and third are not.

What you probably want is to add the restrictions that 1) if one x is null, the other must be as well for them to be equal and 2) same for the ys.

Answer (score 6):

Take these (x,y) pairs:

According to the rules, (1,2)=(1,null)=(1,3), which would lead you to believe that (1,2)=(1,3), which is false. So yes, it's impossible.

Edit: misread a rule, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "if at least one y is null", so you may need to clarify this further, but here's a solution based on how I understand your specifications.

```
public boolean yourEquals(Object x, Object y) {

    if(x != null && y != null) return x.equals(x) && y.equals(y);
    else if(x == null) return y.equals(y);
    else return x.equals(x);

}
```

Please correct my assumptions if I've made flawed ones, but your description of the problem is somewhat difficult to understand in places.

**EDIT:** Of course, this relationship isn't transitive.  As stated above, no relationship with your requirements *can* be transitive.  But this is the function which will return a boolean based on your three rules.